# Is the Wikipedia formula for the Gauss equation correct?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I've been doing some computations and they don't seem to add up:

Consider an $n$-sphere immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Its Riemann tensor should be of the form $R_{abcd} = p *(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$, $p>0$.

Its second fundamental form should be of the form $\Pi_{ab}= k*g_{ab}$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations#Formal_statement

Wikipedia states that for $M\subset P$, the Gauss equation is 
[image]
with $X,Y,Z,W\in TM$ .

Now, if I apply the Gauss equation for $P=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, M= \mathbb{S}^n$, then $R'$ vanishes leaving $R_{abcd} = (-k^{2}) (g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$.

However $-k^2$ should be positive which is why I suspect the Wikipedia formula has $R$ and $R'$ switched around.

This is not the only place I've seen the formula like this. I'm really confused. Can you help me figure out where the error is?

Edit: Knowing $R_{bd} = {R^{c}}_{bcd}$ and R = ${R^{a}}_a$,  ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition#The_pieces_appearing_in_the_decomposition)), a curvature tensor $R_{abcd} = (-k^{2}) (g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$ 
would result in 
a scalar curvature of

$R= -k^2(n(n-1)) < 0$ for the sphere. The scalar curvature of the sphere should be positive.

Comment: I didn't check any of your calculations, but I just wanted to note that there are competing conventions for the Riemann curvature tensor, and the two conventions differ in sign!

Comment: Hm, that would make sense, but it's the first I've heard of it. Anyway, I'm using the convention consistent with [this](https://i.imgur.com/c2ELfN3.png), which is also taken from another article on Wikipedia: [Ricci decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition#The_pieces_appearing_in_the_decomposition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Jason DeVito's advice that there are two conventions, long discussions with Seub, and checking the computations of various formulas on Wikipedia pages, I've come up with the following heuristic for Wikipedia formulas:

1)Equations written using linear operator notation use one convention:
$$\langle R(X,Y)Z, W \rangle =  \langle \Pi (Y, Z),   \Pi(X, W)\rangle -   \langle \Pi (X, Z),   \Pi(Y, W)\rangle $$
$$R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$
(see [Gauss Codazzi Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations#Formal_statement), [Second Fundamental Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form#Generalization_to_arbitrary_codimension),[Ricci Curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Definition))

2)Equations written using Ricci calculus/Tensor notation use the opposite convention:
$$ R_{xyzw}  =  \Pi_{xz}   \Pi_{yw} -  \Pi_{yz}   \Pi_{xw}$$
$$A_{v;pq}-A_{v;qp}= A_{\beta}{R^{\beta}}_{vpq}$$
(see [Riemann_curvature_tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression),[List of formulas in Riemannian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Riemann_curvature_tensor))

---

The idea is to swap the sign of the Riemann curvature tensor when transcribing between tensor notation and operator notation. I haven't seen any formula in Wikipedia that doesn't agree with this heuristic.

I myself prefer tensor notation, and am used to said convention, tough many do Riemannian geometry using operators and may be using the opposite convention.

**Edit:** The convention [does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Riemann_curvature_tensor) appear written out explicitly: 
$$R^\rho{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} = dx^\rho(R(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})\partial_{\sigma})$$
It's weird, but all the Wiki's formulas seem to follow it.

Comment: It's not that simple: the wikipedia page for Ricci curvature has the definition of the Ricci tensor off by a minus sign, even when they define it using linear operator notation. Anyway, I find that it would have been fair to accept my answer, since I gave you all the answers and the explanations to your questions.

Comment: You have to change the sign of the Riemann tensor when switching between operator notation and tensor notation:

In operator notation, they define 
$R(\eta,\xi) = tr_{\zeta} (\zeta\rightarrow R(\zeta,\eta)\xi )$. 
Using  simpler variable names, this is  $R(b,c) = tr_{a} (a\rightarrow R(a,b)c )$ . Using and "ad-literam" translation would result in "$R_{bc} = {R^{a}}_{bca}$" . But we remember that we have to change the sign of the Riemann curvature when going from operator notation and tensor notation. This results in $R_{bc} = {R^{a}}_{bac}$, which agrees with the rest of the article.

Comment: Your answer was very important in helping to figure out the "pattern" Wikipedia uses , but I could not agree with its conclusion that all those definitions were simply wrong.  This is why I did not accept it.

Comment: They're wrong in the sense that they're inconsistent. I made it clear that *given their definition of the Riemann curvature tensor*, their definition of the Ricci tensor and of space forms were wrong. It's not about tensor notation vs operator notation.

Comment: If you only examine formulas in one notation or in the other, they will form a consistent picture. The problem is, when translating between the two pictures, you have to change the sign of the Riemann tensor. If you take into account  ***how*** the formula is written (tensor or operator), you can interpret it correctly. It's more of a "one thing under two names" situation. I've never seen this convention written out explicitly, but that's a different problem.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but I don't agree with it. Also, I just realized that in the wikipedia page for the Riemann curvature tensor they write that $R^\rho{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} = dx^\rho(R(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})\partial_{\sigma})$. That is not the convention I've been assuming! And you neither, apparently. I don't know why they would choose that. But it doesn't seem to be consistent with what is written in the Ricci curvature page. At this point I give up, I don't care what weird notations and sign mistakes the wikipedia editors have chosen.

Comment: $R^\rho{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} = dx^\rho(R(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})\partial_{\sigma})$ . So they do write it out explicitly. Yeah, that makes sense. I mean, it agrees with what I've been saying. All our problems came because we weren't using Wikipedia's convention when translating between formulas in "left-side" style (tensor) and "right-side" style (operator).  Even tough this convention is weird, all the Wikis formulas obey it. So there isn't inconsistency in the Wikipedia articles, just obscurity.

Comment: I think there's still a problem with the Ricci curvature page

Comment: I've checked that. It works out if you apply the Wikis convention (see my first comment).

Comment: But they don't follow the same convention for how to go from operator notation to tensor notation as in the page for riemann curvature.

Comment: I haven't found any mistakes for the formulas I've checked (as long as I follow the Wikipedia convention) . See [here](https://imgur.com/a/ejWPlhw) for detailed prof on the Ricci tensor formula. If you still think there's a contradiction you can point to exactly which formulas in the Wiki are contradictory, and I'll examine them. But, like I've said, I haven't found any so far.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well in the Ricci page they write $R_{ij} = {R^k}_{ikj}$ instead of $R_{ij} = {R^k}_{jki}$ like you, but these two expressions are equal using the symmetries of the Riemann tensor.

Comment: Whops. That was my mistate. I wrote the  formula as $R(\eta,\xi) = tr_{\zeta} (\zeta\rightarrow R(\zeta,\eta)\xi )\hspace{1cm}$ (2) , when Wikipedia said $(\xi,\eta)$ (see [here](https://imgur.com/a/v7AzdSs) ) .

Answer (score 3):

First, as Jason deVito points out, there are indeed two different conventions for the Riemann curvature tensor, differing by a minus sign. But you and Wikipedia both use the more common one. Not only that, as an independent matter, there are also two different conventions for the second fundamental form, also differing by a minus sign. Here I believe that is that the second fundamental for
on the sphere should be $$\Pi = - \sqrt{k} \, g = - \frac{1}{r} g$$ instead of $\Pi = \sqrt{k} \, g$. This is if we follow Wikipedia's sign convention (the more common one I believe) that $\Pi(u, v) = \langle \nabla_u v, n\rangle =  \langle -\nabla_u n, v\rangle$ where $n$ is the unit normal. Note that the sign of the second fundamental depends crucially on the choice of the unit normal $n$ for your hypersurface. The unit normal is determined by choosing an orientation of both the manifold $P$ and the submanifold $M$. Here if you take the usual orientation of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and of $S^n$, you must choose the outward pointing normal for $n$.

That being said, even if you get the sign wrong on the second fundamental form, you get the same Gauss equation (following Wikipedia's formula), namely
$$\langle R(X,Y)Z, W \rangle = k (\langle Y, Z\rangle \langle X, W\rangle - \langle X, Z\rangle \langle Y, W\rangle)$$
or following your notations $$R_{abcd} = k (g_{ad}g_{bc} - g_{ac}g_{bd}) = -k (g_{ac}g_{bd} - g_{ad}g_{bc})$$ But contrary to what you seem to think, there is no sign problem here, this is indeed what you expect for a Riemannian manifold of constant sectional curvature $k$.

**EDIT:** To answer your new question about Ricci and scalar curvature: I agree this is confusing. If we take your definition of the Ricci tensor, which agrees with Wikipedia's, namely
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Ric}(X,Y) = \operatorname{tr}(V \mapsto R(X,V)Y)
\end{equation}
or, as you put it, $R_{bd} = {R^c}_{bcd}$, then we find

\begin{align}
R_{bd} &= {R^c}_{bcd} = k({g^c}_d g_{bc} -  {g^c}_c g_{bd} )\\
&= -k(n-1)g_{bd}
\end{align}
in other words $\operatorname{Ric} = -k(n-1)g$, where $n$ is the dimension of $M$. I agree with you that this is not what we want usually. Therefore the conclusion is that we must take the opposite sign convention in the definition of the Ricci tensor. I think the confusion comes from the fact that some authors take the opposite sign convention for the Riemann curvature tensor. By the way, here is the convention I use, I have not written it yet:
$$R(X,Y) = \nabla_{X,Y}^2 - \nabla_{Y,X}^2$$
in other words
$$R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$

This definition agrees with that of Wikipedia in the pages [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) and [Ricci curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature). But the conclusion is that I disagree with their definition of the Ricci tensor by a minus sign. I also disagree with their sign in the paragraphs "Ricci Curvature" and "Special Cases" in the page [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor). As for the page [Ricci decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition), I also disagree with the sign of the Ricci tensor, unless they take the opposite sign convention for the Riemann curvature tensor (it's not defined explicitly in that page). If you research, you'll see that quite a few authors choose the opposite sign convention for the Riemann curvature tensor (e.g. Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine), which is probably the source of confusion.

**EDIT2:** More fighting about signs: see comments under OP's answer.

Comment: I used a variable $k$ because I didn't need to compute every detail. Observe the second fundamental form in the Gauss equation. It always appears squared with itself: $\Pi(X,Z)\Pi(Y,W) - \Pi(Y,Z)\Pi(X,W)$ .So it really doesn't matter if I swap its sign or choose the opposite normal field. The problem is with the other two terms (the submanifold curvature and ambient curvature) having switched places.

Comment: Yes. The Gauss equation from the [second fundamental form article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) is correct, but I believe the one from the [Gauss-codazy equations article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations#Formal_statement) article needs to have $R$ and $R'$ swapped. Its result needs to be the submanifold curvature, not the curvature of the ambient space. Then the two equations would match up.

Comment: I don't agree, I checked and think both formulas are the same, just written slightly differently. Double check. Don't forget that $\langle R(X,Y)Z, W \rangle = - \langle R(X,Y)W, Z \rangle$.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that now.  I didn't see $Z$ and $W$ were swapped. Sorry about that. Those two articles agree. However, as far as I know, the scalar curvature $R$ is the trace of the Ricci $R_{bd}$ tensor, and the Ricci tensor is obtained by contracting the first and third index of the Riemann tensor ${R^{c}}_{bcd}   =  R_{bd}$ . (taken form [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition#The_pieces_appearing_in_the_decomposition) ) .Won't the above formulas result in negative scalar curvature for the sphere?

Comment: I edited my answer to address the problem with the sign of the Ricci tensor (and therefore of the scalar curvature). Let me know if you agree.

Comment: I've been doing some computations, and the convention you used to define the Riemann tensor,ie $R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$  (taken from [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Ricci_curvature) will give $R_{abcd} = k (g_{ac}g_{bd} - g_{ad}g_{bc})$ on the sphere. So the Ricci tensor, as given in that article, is correct for the convention it used.  Continued in second comment.

Comment: The problem is there are two conventions: the articles on "sectional curvature", "Gauss codazzy equation" and "second fundamental form" use "convention 1", where the Rieman curvature on the sphere is   $R_{abcd} = -k (g_{ac}g_{bd} - g_{ad}g_{bc})$ , and all the other articles use "convention 2" where the curvature has the opposite sign: $R_{abcd} = k (g_{ac}g_{bd} - g_{ad}g_{bc})$ .I prefer "convention 2", because if I consider the Riemman tensor as a norm on the space of $2$-forms, I want pozitive curvature to give pozitive norms ie. $R_{1212}$ should have the same sign as the curvature.

Comment: Still, it's confusing that there are 2 conventions used on Wikipedia. Anyway, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: I don't agree that  my convention for the Riemann tensor gives the formula you say on the sphere. I insist that gives mine (see answer), i.e. minus yours. (But then the sectional curvature is something like $R_{ijji}$, not $R_{ijij}$.) And so I also insist that the Ricci tensor given in the "Riemann curvature tensor" wikipedia page is wrong.

Comment: You're correct.  Let's translate $R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$ as tensors. We get: ${R_{xyk}}^{p}Z^{k} = Z^{p}_{;yx}- Z^{p}_{;xy}$ .Rearanging and moving the indices, it can be written as:  $Z_{k}{R^{k}}_{pxy} = Z_{k;yx}- Z_{k;xy}$.  However, this is the exact opposite of what it says [here:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression) $A_{v;pq}-A_{v;qp}= A_{\beta}{R^{\beta}}_{vpq}$.

Comment: After staring around at the Wikipedia formulas, here's my conclusion: every Wikipedia formula written using operator notation (think $\nabla_{X} Z$, $R(X,Y)$) uses your convention ($R_{1221}$), and every Wikipedia formula written using tensor notation ($Z_{;a}X^{a}, R_{abcd}$) uses mine  ($R_{1212}$),. You'd have to correct a lot of tensor-index expressions if you want to make them all match.

Comment: Good, I'm glad we reached the same conclusion! If you want to do a good deed, you could suggest modifying the wikipedia pages (in the discussion tab).